# error:: could not find rake-11.1.2 in any of the sources run `bundle install` to install missing gems

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

I get the above error after i use `msfupdate` for the first time and type `msfconsole`. After installing guest additions on kali linux.  I googled it and came across a similiar question on reddit but had no answer. I tried              `apt-get install bundle install` but it did not work.  I also searched unix and linux but I did not find this question.

Comment: Not sure if any of [this](https://github.com/cantino/huginn/issues/1395) is helpful, but the person doing the helping here seems very knowledgeable & maybe some of this will point you in the right direction even if it's slightly different?

Comment: Did you try running `bundle install`? Not `apt-get install bundle install`, just `bundle install` at the root of the project.

Comment: Yes I tried `bundle install`.   It says running as root will break the system and could not locate gemfile or .bundle/directory.

Comment: Hmm... How about running that as a non-root user? In addition, where did you run that?

Comment: I ran it in kali linux terminal, I don't know how to log out of root in kali because it is root by default, in say ubuntu you can use control d or exit but that doesnt work.

Comment: I meant, in what directory did you run the command? In addition, what's the output of `rake --version` and `type rake`?

Comment: I ran it in /root directory.  The output of `rake --version` is   rake, version 10.4.2.  And output of `type rake` is   rake is hashed (/usr/bin/rake)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41491/discussion-between-franklin-yu-and-linuxuser001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try    `apt-get install ruby`.  Then if you still can't connect do `apt-get install openssl`, then go to `cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework` and type `bundle install`, thats it, now `msfconsole` should work properly. This will install the missing gems.

Answer (score 1):

This should indicate your problem:

```
could not locate gemfile or .bundle/directory. – Linuxuser001 Jun 22 at 8:07
```

It's looking for a program that's just not there, you need to install Ruby:

`apt-get -f install Ruby`

Comment: This worked for me after a msfupdate that caused the OP's problem. I had to also install zlib-dev (sudo apt-get install libz-dev) for a dependency (nokogiri) to compile and install though.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to install ruby, its already installed on kali,
just move on your current working directory in terminal.

ex.

```
cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework
```

and type

```
bundle install
```

it fix your problem.

**Update:**

before installing **bundle**
install libpcap-dev

```
apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework/ ; bundle install
```

Comment: explain your answer why & how ?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work...http://pastebin.com/exX1YsbV

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of hello moto's solution above, which actually worked for me.